# Nodejs trim() is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, trim

I get this error when I run and can not seem to resolve it.

`TypeError: data[key].trim is not a function`

The function is this one

```
const generateSignature = (data, passPhrase = null) => {
  // Create parameter string
  let pfOutput = "";
  for (let key in data) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      if (data[key] !== "") {
        pfOutput += `${key}=${encodeURIComponent(data[key].trim()).replace(
          /%20/g,
          " + "
        )}&`;
      }
    }
  }

  // Remove last ampersand
  let getString = pfOutput.slice(0, -1);
  if (passPhrase !== null) {
    getString += `&passphrase=${encodeURIComponent(passPhrase.trim()).replace(
      /%20/g,
      "+"
    )}`;
  }

  return crypto.createHash("md5").update(getString).digest("hex");
};
```

I am not sure how to solve this problem

Comment: What is the value of `data[key]` when the error happens? It doesn't seem to be a string but that's we can say with any amount of confidence. There is no information beyond what the error message says. The way to fix it would be to avoid calling string methods on non-strings - either avoid having non-strings or skip them when trimming and replacing. I don't know what the goal here is.

Comment: Which version of Node.js are you running, just in case?

Comment: I am using version npm 5.6.0

Comment: npm has a different version to node. They are two different applications. Try `node --version`

Comment: Node version is v15.8.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a possibility what `data[key]` isn't a string type.

try this:

Change `if(data[key] !== "")` to `if(typeof data[key] === "string")`

Answer (score 0):

trim() works with strings only. Convert integer values into strings like so. Where x is the integer value wrap it in `${x}`